# Passing python variable to embedded shell script?

Tags: bash, python, variable

I have an existing python code and i need to call a bash script from inside. The python code captures few variables and i need this to be passed to my shell to avoid duplicate input from user.

I have created a test script to simulate this, however, i am not able to echo the variables in shell ( it retuns a null )

1): Is it possible to pass the python variable to the shell script being called using subprocess?
2) If the below code can be optimized to achieve this, i am open to feedback.

Python code:

```
import os
import subprocess

first=input("Enter the first ip")
second=input("Enter the second IP")

subprocess.call(['bash','./script.sh',first,second])
```

Bash code (script.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash
###########################
echo "The First IP is $first"
echo "Enter your server "
read faulty_server
echo "The server is $faulty_server"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 1st parameter in the Bash script is not called `$first`, but `$1`.

The 2nd parameter in the Bash script is not called `$faulty_server`, but `$2`.